# miniCRAN package source downloading

Tags: r, cran

I like how it's possible to fix the Rversion with the [miniCRAN package's](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/miniCRAN/miniCRAN.pdf) makeRepo function:

```
makeRepo(pkgs, path, repos = getOption("repos"), type = "source",
         Rversion = R.version, download = TRUE, writePACKAGES = TRUE,
         quiet = FALSE)
```

The documentation says Rversion is ignored if type="source".  Does anyone know why?  Is this a limitation of CRAN in general?  It would be really nice to have this functionality, and I'm not sure of a way around it.

Answer (score 0):

I e-mailed the author/maintainer of miniCRAN a slightly more specific question, and I received an answer.  For those of you with a similar question, I'll point you to the following link, where this correspondence has taken the form of a Github issue:

https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/miniCRAN/issues/64